# jQuery: Prevent click on sub-element's class: redirect page on tr click EXCEPT certain td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

I've been searching for like 30 minutes already, so I apologize if I missed this answer already.  I've seen a lot of CLOSE ones, but none quite like this.

I have an imported JavaScript function which is used in several files.  It makes it so any table whose row has a `clickable-row` class will redirect to the `href` attribute, thereby making the whole row act like an anchor tag.

However, on some pages I'll have on `td` be populated with a checkbox, which I want to be able to click WITHOUT the page redirecting (so I can select multiple rows in the table).

Here is my current function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.clickable-row').click(function() {
        window.document.location = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

I want it to do something like the following, but this doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.clickable-row').click(function() {
        if(!jQuery(this).closest('td').hasClass('skip-click')) {
            window.document.location = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Why don't you just add a class to the parent, when you actually want it to be clickable (e.g. instead of skip-click do-click or something).

Then you could do jQuery('td.do-click .clickable-row').click(function() { ...} without checking anything within the click function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [e.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

`this` inside the handler will refer to the `.clickable-row` element, not the element which actually triggered the click. The target property of the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) will return the element that triggered the event.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.clickable-row').click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).closest('td').hasClass('skip-click')) {
            window.document.location = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```